# InDesign: gap between footnotes

Tags: adobe-indesign, footnotes

I need to reduce space between footnotes in InDesign.

Please see image below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h-PQS4PHcULzl7IJFkmzQ9VTkBJ0iGWg/view

"Space Between Footnotes" in "Document Footnotes Option" is already set to 0.
Footnotes paragraph style has no spacing before or after, I tried changing it's leading.
No joy.

I tried changing footnotes charactert style leading.
No joy.

I use nested character style for drop caps in footnotes.
I tried changing its leading.
No joy.

I searched forums and tryed all kind of possible solutions.
Nothing worked for me.

Any help?

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look here for solution:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/indesign/gap-between-footnotes-solved/m-p/10804888

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Feel free to browse the site, ask more question, upvote quality content and maybe leave an answer of your own.